# Multiple Optional Route Params in AngularJS Not Working

Tags: angularjs

How is is possible to define ONE route with TWO optional params and to allow NONE, ONE, OR BOTH of the params to be supplied?..

```
http://localhost/login
http://localhost/login/abc123
http://localhost/login/abc123/joe.blow@nowhere.com
```

I've read the docs on [UrlMatcher](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher) and looked at several SO questions.  Nothing seems to work.  I cannot resolve the basic route (no params) once optional params are defined on a UI-Router route.  No errors are produced, but the view is never displayed.  The only way to force this to work is to define THREE different routes:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
$stateProvider
.state("login", {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "login/login.html",
    params: {
        appId: null,
        emailAddress: null
    }
})
.state("loginWithAppId", {
    url: "/login/:appId",
    templateUrl: "login/login.html",
    params: {
        appId: null,
        emailAddress: null
    }
})
.state("loginWithParams", {
    url: "/login/:appId/:emailAddress",
    templateUrl: "login/login.html",
    params: {
        appId: null,
        emailAddress: null
    }
});
```

My goal is to only have ONE route but to allow NONE, ONE, OR BOTH of the params to be sent in:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
$stateProvider
.state("login", {
    url: "/login/:appId/:emailAddress",
    templateUrl: "login/login.html",
    params: {
        appId: null,
        emailAddress: null
    }
});
```

Comment: to be clear, when you say NONE, ONE, or BOTH, you mean NONE, AppID only, or AppId and emailAddress, correct?

Comment: Correct.  I've also tried adding a ? to the route URL and a / to the browser's URL.  No view or console error is ever displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Plunker with your code and just one state with multiple optional routes:

http://plnkr.co/edit/rgi9MoDKI5ncJcnchb4j?p=preview

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="appController as appCtrl">
<a ui-sref='login({appId:null,emailAddress:null})'>login(NONE)</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a ui-sref='login({appId:123,emailAddress:null})'>login(ONE)</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a ui-sref="login({appId:123,emailAddress:'a@b.com'})">login(BOTH)</a>
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

Config:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("login", {
    url: "/login/:appId/:emailAddress",
    params: {
      appId: null,
      emailAddress: null
    },
    templateUrl: "login.html",
    controller: 'LoginController',
    controllerAs: 'LoginCtrl'
 })
})
```

Controller:

```
.controller('LoginController',function($stateParams){
  var self = this;

  self.appId = $stateParams.appId;
  self.emailAddress = $stateParams.emailAddress;
});
```

Login Page:

```
<div>appId:{{LoginCtrl.appId}}</div>
<div>emailAddress:{{LoginCtrl.emailAddress}}</div>
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: I just submitted an edit to the links to allow for navigation back to less specific parameters from more specific parameters.